# Query 2nd table with value of the 1st

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my db, **departments** and **company_com**. What I am trying to do is, if a posted value in php is run in a query, check the first table for a value and if found, query the second table with that value.

So, for example, posted value = **demo**, I run select query to store the value in a variable and then use that variable in query on **company_com**. I know how to query tables but not sure how to store the value in a variable in php. Thanks

BTW I am using MySql and not pdo or mysqli.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: sounds like a poor approach, you should use a join and a single query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12475850/1450077 You might want to check this out

Comment: Never mind. Decided to go another route. Shall request the question be closed.

Comment: you can delete your own question. it is a beginner question, that is why people downvoted on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT data1 FROM firsttable");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT data2 FROM secondtable WHERE data2 = '".$row[0]."'");
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        echo $row2[0];
    }
}
```

- $result1 is first query.
- first while loop goes through first query
- $result2 is second query which takes WHERE data from first query's
  results.
- second loop goes through second query and echos data from second
  query which we compared to data from first query.

  Hope that made any sense.